# SharePoint 2016 workflow management service application is missing

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, central-administration, workflow-manager

First of all, the work management service application is not in the new service creation list (manage service application).

When I try to create a SharePoint 2013 workflow, I am not getting the option to create a SharePoint 2013 workflow in platform type. So I chose SharePoint 2010 and started creating a workflow (for testing purposes I simply created email sending workflow when new item is added).

After creating and publishing, when tested the workflow is not triggering.

Then I tried again to create a simple approval workflow (Out of Box), but it gives me the following error

> The form cannot be rendered. This may be due to a misconfiguration of the Microsoft SharePoint Server State Service. For more information, contact your server administrator

I also installed and configured the Workflow manager 1.0. even though I am unsuccessful in resolving it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to Get the SharePoint 2013 workflows Option in Designer, You have to Install and Configure.

- Installation of Workflow Manager 1.0
- Configuration of Workflow Manager
- Install the Workflow Clients on the All server in the farm( if wfm not install on them)
- Register workflow Proxy with SharePoint Server.

To publish the Workflow you have to provision the App management and Subscription Settings service as well otherwise publishing will fail.

After this you will see the Workflow Option.check this
[SharePoint 2013/ 2106 : Tips for Sucessfull Installation of Workflow Manager](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33952.sharepoint-2013-2106-tips-for-sucessfull-installation-of-workflow-manager.aspx)